# MVC 5 partial view and using woes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have moved the contents of an index.cshtml to a partial view, but now I am getting compilation errors whereby MVC can't find the namespaces I am importing. The errors relate to an extension method.

At the top of the partial view, I am using the namespace:

```
 @using Infrastructure.ExtensionMethods
```

And, for good measure, I am including the namespace in the web.config in my views folder:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="CYC.EformsPrototype" />
    <add namespace="CYC.EformsPrototype.Infrastructure.ExtensionMethods"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

But I am still getting the compilation error. I have read many posts on stackoverflow but none of them answered the question. Can anyone help?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I was missing a @model clause from the top of my partial view.

Mark